# IDEA: Grails SDK is not selected

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

How do I set up Grails with IntelliJ IDEA? I have the ultimate edition. `sdkman` installed Grails in `/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/bin/grails`
 but if I choose that folder as the SDK, IDEA says: `The selected directory is not a valid home for Grails SDK`

How do I set up an IDEA project with Grails?

`grails -version` from the terminal provides me the following:

```
| Grails Version: 3.2.8
| Groovy Version: 2.4.10
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_121
```

So it's definitely there..

Comment: You do not need SDK to create and develop Grails 3.x apps anymore. Use Grails Application Forge

Comment: If you still want to create an app using SDK please select proper version, i.e. not current

Comment: BTW you are trying to select /bin/grails while the right way is to select the directory which contains /bin: `/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.2.8/`

Comment: Oh ok. Idea complained about missing the Groovy SDK, but I chose the Java SDK and now it doesn't give a billion errors.. Strange..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to select a grails SDK with your version. Import a project from existing sources -> double click the `build.gradle` file - it will import and setup everything correctly - Assuming IntelliJ 2016.x or 2017.x

Video of process here: http://guides.grails.org/grails-quickcasts-developing-grails-3-applications-with-intellij-idea/guide/index.html

Edit: I see what your saying now, you can't select `current` in sdkman - use `/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.2.8`

Comment: So there's no way I can start a new project in IDEA and select "Grails" as a template? It's there as a possibility?

Comment: Your solution didn't work by the way; while I can create the project manually and import it into IDEA, it will still complain that `Groovy SDK is not configured for 'grails' `

Answer (score 1):

The question was for Grails installed with sdkman, but in case anybody comes looking in here and they have installed Grails with brew, you can `brew info grails` and find something like this in the output:

`The GRAILS_HOME directory is:
  /usr/local/opt/grails/libexec`

This path will work in the IntelliJ new-project dialog to set up the SDK.